# Should web worker be used to handle style rendering in css-in-js?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, css-in-js

I am writing a css-in-js library, and I came across web worker recently, and I learnt how it can help me run code in parallel.

As the main thread is treated as UI thread, should I push some of the css-generating works from my library to web-worker? Would this be considered as anti-pattern?

Comment: is this just for experiment? if it is for the real life use cases, I dont think it is a good idea since the css should be generated before it is loaded to client

Comment: Kind of. But i can generate css beforehand as well using web worker, as it is implemented in node too.

Comment: but it is an extra step unnecessary on client.

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic rule. You move something to web worker to make page operable during the calculation. In case of css-in-js in most of cases page should wait css to do something, so usage of workers looks limited there. The only case i see - web worker could prepare the skin update in background without the page blocking. Generally speaking, you need some real project to check is it a good idea